# Uninstalling VirtualBox breaks GNOME?

Tags: fedora, virtualbox

I am having some trouble with removing Virtualbox from my system.

I first tried to remove it using dnf commands, but realized that I had used the installer from virtualbox.org at some point to install a specific version. When I downloaded the installer again (now for v7.0) and typed `sudo ./virtualbox.run uninstall`.
It removed the existing version (6.1 i think) successfully, but suddenly my gnome desktop was not working properly. Icons was gone, and I was not able to display any gnome apps, but some other programs worked.
I tried reinstalling most of the gnome packages, but it did not help.

After `ctrl` + `alt` +`f2` and logging in, I ran the virtualbox installer from there and – voila! Gnome was back to normal, but now virtualbox is back on my system!

So, how do I get rid of virtualbox, without causing any bad side effects (not sure if it's gnome or something else that gets thrown out with virtualbox using the installer, though)? I am actually not sure if I even completed the virtualbox configuration in the first place to compile the kernel drivers etc on this current system, if that makes a difference?

I'm on a fully updated Fedora 36 Workstation.

Any help is much appreciated!

Update:

I tried to follow the log file as I uninstalled again today, but nothing of interest happened at first, but later I could see this when trying to open Nautilus:

```
Dec 13 12:34:34 fedora nautilus[9463]: Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.
                                       This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
Dec 13 12:34:34 fedora nautilus[9463]: **
Dec 13 12:34:34 fedora nautilus[9463]: Gtk:ERROR:../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /usr/share/icons/Adwaita/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
Dec 13 12:34:34 fedora nautilus[9463]: Bail out! Gtk:ERROR:../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load
Dec 13 12:45:24 fedora gnome-shell[1783]: gdk_cairo_surface_create_from_pixbuf: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
```

I have tried to reinstall some packages:

```
sudo dnf reinstall gtk3 gtk4  gdk-pixbuf2 gdk-pixbuf2-modules jxl-pixbuf-loader
```

But it is still not back to normal. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Did you install the latest virtualbox using dnf?

Comment: Hi, no I uninstalled vb6.1 (causing broken system) and then later installed, uninstalled and then again installed vb7.0 using the installer _All distributions_ from here: [link]https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads
The extra uninstall and install steps was to test if the installer script perhaps would not brake the system if it uninstalled the most recent virtualbox, but it did, so I had to install it one last time to have a usable laptop again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
So the problem was not so serious as it visually looked. The uninstall script from VirtualBox broke the MIME database, so after running the following command and logging out and back in, everything was back to normal:

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

PS: I found the command [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1351607/gtk-warning-could-not-load-a-pixbuf-from-icon-theme). Might be some other useful info there for others as well.